# HTTP 404 Error on selecting "Open app" from Heroku Dashboard for a Python Telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, http-status-code-404, telegram

I've set up an Heroku account and deployed my first app - a simple Python Telegram bot - to the Heroku platform,  This Telegram bot is working fine from its Heroku-hosted location, in as much as it's correctly responding to supported commands I enter into Telegram.

However, when I select the "**Open app**" button from the *Heroku Dashboard*, this returns an HTTP 404: Not Found error.  Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

**Open app** button opens the home page of your web app.

If your app is a telegram bot, it means that exposes some http endpoints to receive the telegram notifications

`localhost:8082/api/bot/messages`

If this is your case, the **Open app** button is trying to access:

`localhost:8082` or `localhost:8082/`

If you have not configures a controller, router o page in the root of your web **/**, 404 will be returned (not only in heroku)

Try to add a simple page for the root of python web app. Example with **bottle** framework:

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome to my bot'
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082)
```

Comment: Thank you JRichardsz for your reply!

In my case the Open app button is trying to access the first of the URLs that I was assigned when I initially created the app.  With reference to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps), and following the example below:

 heroku create example
 Creating ⬢ example... done
 https://example.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/example.git
 
I was assigned the following URL (where "example" represents the app name I chose):

 https://example.herokuapp.com/